# eshell goes to the bottom of the page after executing a command

Tags: eshell

when I execute a command on eshell the prompt switches to the bottom of the window. I have to `C-l` a few times to get it back on top. Once again after I execute anything it goes back to the bottom of the window. It is infuriating. How do I make sure the eshell prompt stays on 'top' of the window at all times with the previous commands being hidden above the window. I don't know if 'window' is correct terminology. Please correct me if not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can disable the Eshell's scroll feature using:

```el
(add-hook 'eshell-mode-hook
          (defun chunyang-eshell-mode-setup ()
            (remove-hook 'eshell-output-filter-functions
                         'eshell-postoutput-scroll-to-bottom)))
```

Notes, `(eval-after-load "eshell" (remove-hook ...))` doesn't work correctly according to my experiment, it simply sets `eshell-output-filter-functions` to nil, I don't know the cause. You can also use the Custom interface with:

```
M-x customize-option RET eshell-output-filter-functions RET
```

this way works too and is much easier, since this option is available until Eshell has been invoked, if you can't find this option, type `M-x eshell` then try again.

Comment: I do not have eshell-output-filter-functions option available. What should I do?

Comment: @JackDawkins I am not sure what's your meaning. Emacs 24.3 has this option, probably some earlier versions has it too. Besides, the option is only available AFTER Eshell has been invoked.

Comment: Yes, indeed it worked after I invoked eshell. Thanks.

Comment: Well it goes back to doing what it did before in the middle of an editing session. scrolls to the bottom. I made sure I 'apply and save' it. Why is this happening?

Comment: I usually execute clear command in zsh when my workspace gets cluttered. I did the same in eshell. The saved setting gets deleted when I do this it seems

Comment: @JackDawkins You can type `C-h v eshell-output-filter-functions` in the Eshell buffer to see if `eshell-postoutput-scroll-to-bottom` is actually removed. I don't think it's related to Eshell's `clear` (added in Emacs 25.1), it simply inserts many newlines to occupy the whole screen, thus the prompt always goes to the very bottom.

Answer (score 3):

You might check whether `eshell-scroll-to-bottom-on-output` is set to `nil`. Here's the documentation:

> Documentation:
>   Controls whether interpreter output causes window to scroll.
>   If nil, then do not scroll.  If t or ‘all’, scroll all windows showing
>   buffer.  If ‘this’, scroll only the selected window.  If ‘others’,
>   scroll only those that are not the selected window.

Comment: Where exactly do I change this?. I don't have any customizations for eshell on my .emacs.d/init.el file.

Comment: If you do `M-x Customize` and then type `eshell` it will take you to the customize screen. Scroll down and you'll see the setting. Or alternately, just put `(setq eshell-scroll-to-bottom-on-output nil)` in your init.el file.

Comment: It gives me the following four options.1. Do not scroll eshell windows. 2. scroll all windows showing the buffer 3. scroll only the selected window.
4. scroll all windows other than selected. Which one should I choose?. I am confused.

Comment: Since you don't want to go to the bottom of the window it should be set to 1.  do not scroll. Or you can do the `setq` option that I mention above.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `eshell-scroll-show-maximum-output` to `nil`.

Sadly the documentation doesn't really explain the difference to `eshell-scroll-to-bottom-on-output`, but its default value is `nil` anyway and therefore isn't responsible for the described behaviour. In contrast the default of `eshell-scroll-show-maximum-output` is `t`.

My understanding is that enabling `eshell-scroll-to-bottom-on-output` causes eshell to scroll to the bottom if you have scrolled upwards the buffer and you have a program running which produces some output. It will just scroll in a way though, that the last line will be visible in the buffer, and will not align the last line to the bottom of the window.

An enabled `eshell-scroll-show-maximum-output` on the other hand ignores output produced by a third party program when you scroll upwards, but will align the current prompt with the bottom of the window (hence "maximising" the last output) when you issue any kind of input with triggers a new prompt.

Comment: Please consider elaborating, explaining how this answers the question.